# Breaking up a double integral where the integrand is a simple product

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

This is from the book Further Mathematics for Economic Analysis:

$\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y e^{-|u|-|v|} \ dvdu$

The double integral was rewritten as:

$\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-|u|} \ du \times\int_{-\infty}^y e^{-|v|} \ dv$

I was not aware that an integrand could be split up that way; I thought it was always supposed to be solved holding one variable constant and doing one integration at a time. Is this a special property of the exponential, a special property of this specific function, or something else?

Comment: So that is the only condition to achieve that second equality?

Comment: That's a seperable integral. If you can write the integrand as a product of two single-variable functions, and the integrals don't depend on eachother, then you can split them into their own integral.

Comment: You don't see this much because double integrals are rarely independent. But it's nice when you can do this.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Thank you